# Open Source Command Line Tools to Remove Hyperlinks in PDFs?

Tags: command-line, pdf

Are there any Open Source Tools to Remove PDF links in Ubuntu.  I use PDFtk and i am not able to find any internal links in it. Due to the Internal links my python script that uses PyPdf to merge the PDF files into one file fails.

Answer (score 3):

A simple step to remove all the hyper links from a PDF is by printing, that is by choosing print to file option.
but this process doesn't remove the highlight of the hyper link.
hope this helps

Comment: Helps, but bookmarks can get lost by doing that. A solution for that issue is using the program [jpdfbookmarks](http://flavianopetrocchi.blogspot.it/).

Answer (score 2):

For PDF-files generated with latex and hyperref the following works:

`sed '/Link/d' < file.pdf > file-without-links.pdf`

This command removes all lines containing the string `Link` from the file, which (in my case) were responsible for defining the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

When I extract the pages from a PDF with pdftk and assemble them again afterwards the links are gone. Example:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
pdftk ../FileWithLinks.pdf burst
pdftk *.pdf cat output ../FileWithLinksRemoved.pdf
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I was using `pdftk 2.02`

Comment: Neither for me `pdftk 2.02`