# Is there any tools to remove all "links" from a PDF file

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm using Lubuntu in my laptop and I have an e-book reader. (Sony Reader PRS-T2)

However, my e-book reader struggles to open several pdf files with links in it, such as webpage I saved using Google's chrome build-in print-to-pdf tool.

Is there any software (CLI or GUI) that can remove those links from my PDF files?

I have have tried "flattening" function from `PDF Chain` and `PDFTK` but they do not work.

P.S. I have tried the solution in
[Open Source Command Line Tools to Remove Hyperlinks in PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106154/open-source-command-line-tools-to-remove-hyperlinks-in-pdfs)
but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: You should ask a new question about why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a way of doing it; I don't think it's intended behaviour exactly, but it works by virtue of `pdfjam` not preserving links in the output (listed as a known issue in its man page, but somewhat helpful for your particular situation).

It uses the `pdfjam` package, so run `sudo apt-get install pdfjam` first. Then simply navigate to the folder containing the pdf file (take as example `foo.pdf`), and run `pdfjam foo.pdf` . It should process it and output as `foo-pdfjam.pdf`, and any hyperlinks should be gone from the output file.

Comment: My Terminal show

  pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 2.08.
  pdfjam: Reading any site-wide or user-specific defaults...
          (none found)
  pdfjam ERROR: can't find pdflatex!

What should I do?

Comment: @siravac: Ah, sorry, PDFJam requires `pdftex` to be installed before it can run. This is included in the package `texlive-base`. Run `sudo apt-get install texlive-base` and then try again.

Comment: You might also need `texlive-latex-recommended`, for the `pdfpages` program (`pdfjam` works as a frontend for `pdfpages`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your pdf reader there might be a "remove links" button under document processes or something similar. You'll have to forgive me I have not used your specific reader before.

Hope this helps